# Controller is not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I am working on a project. I just created a login form, created a module and a controller. But the controller is not working fine.

Here is the code of the view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="loginApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>UltraServe</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="fonts/roboto.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="fonts/roboto-light.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.4/angular.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="Js/Controller/login.js"></script>
<link href="css/slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="login_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="LoginAppController">
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo"> <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a> </div>
        <!--logo end--> 
    </div>
</header>
<section class="page-wrap">
    <div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal login-form" role="form">
    <h2>Sign in to your account</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required />  {{email}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" required /> {{password}}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default red" ng-click="Click()">Sign in</button>
        </div> 
      </div>
    </form>


    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Now here I create module and controller which is not working fine.

```
var loginApp = angular.module('loginApp', []);

loginApp.controller('LoginAppController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.Click = function (name) {
        alert("Email: " + $scope.email + ", Password: " + $scope.password);
    }

}
```

I have gave the `ng-app="loginApp"` in the view and `ng-controller="LoginAppController"`
But it is not working fine. Please help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you expand on what's not working? Any errors?

Comment: when I use controller like this, nothing works fine. Whole AngularJS stops working. when I comment the controller, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
Change your form tag as

```
<form class="form-horizontal login-form" role="form" ng-submit="Click()">
```

And your submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default red">Sign in</button>
```

And in your controller your forgot to put a `)` at the end of your controller

```
loginApp.controller('LoginAppController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.Click = function () {
        alert("Email: " + $scope.email + ", Password: " + $scope.password);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. The actual mistake was that 
")" bracket. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

just do following  changes

```
 $scope.Click = function() 
       {
         //your logic
        }
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input login.js:19
Uncaught Error: No module: loginApp ....

these are the errors

Comment: could you  just  write you controller in   html  file  in  head section  below angularjs script  tag ....then  run